# iphone post to facebook wall

Tags: facebook, post, publish

I am trying to get my iPhone application to post a message to a user's facebook wall.

I have created a facebook app and specified the value of the `kAppId` in my iphone application.

When i test the iphone app in the simulator, i am prompted to authorize the facebook application, which i accept.  however, i then immediately get the message `"safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid"`.

I am trying to troubleshoot this error but am not really getting anywhere.  Could it be because my facebook app currently shows: `"Directory Status: Not Submitted"` ? (I am not able to submit it to the facebook App Directory until i have 5 - 10 users.)

FYI - I have added a "publish to facebook" button in one of my view controllers that responds with the following method:

```
-(IBAction) publishToFacebook {
  facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId];
  [facebook authorize:nil delegate:self];
  NSMutableDictionary* params = 
[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: kAppId, @"app_id", @"http://www.something.com/", @"link", @"http://www.something.com/something.jpg", @"picture", @"My App Name", @"name", @"The Caption...", @"caption", @"The description...", @"description", @"the message...", @"message", nil];
      [facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks.  Looks like i got this figured out.  basically, just follow the instructions on developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#ios) and be sure to prefix your app id with "fb" in the plist file (ex. fb123456789 where the facebook app id is 123456789)

Also, to answer my question, your facebook app does NOT need to be submitted to the directory for it to work with iPhone integration.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your info.plist file with your appid so it knows you to jump back to your app properly?

Comment: I dont have that set in my plist file, will give that a try.  However, just wanted to know - could it be this is not working because my facebook app currently shows: "Directory Status: Not Submitted" ?

A simple way to test this would be to see if someone else is able to get this working with a facebook app that is NOT submitted to the directory.

Comment: No - that won't be the issue. I never submit my apps to the directory and they still work.  That field is just saying users can search for your application (but they can still use it if they know how to access it, like from your iOS app for example).

Comment: ok, i tried updating the plist file as specified in the facebook documentation: [link] (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#ios) 

still same error: "safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid"

basically just want to know if this is because my facebook app is not yet submitted to the directory.